# Browser scroll bar shift after adding an image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, user-interface, browser

I have an event creation page with image upload. After I select an image, the image is previewed in the browser. When I scroll after the image is added, I see bottom scroll bar stays in the middle of the screen until I focus on an input element. e.g When I focus on description text-area the scroll bar in the middle disappears.

Working version is in jsbin, try selecting an image multiple times. The issue in jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/wigawededo/1/edit?html,css,js,output
[image: jsbin picture]

Issue on my computer:

[image: Problem image]

When an image is selected I preview it with this code:

```js
function showImage() {
  var imageSelector = document.getElementById("image");
  var image = document.getElementById("image").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    const prevImage = document.querySelector("#previewImage");
    if (prevImage) prevImage.parentNode.removeChild(prevImage);

    const prevImageLabel = document.querySelector("#previewImageLabel");
    if (prevImage) prevImageLabel.parentNode.removeChild(prevImageLabel);

    var newImage = document.createElement("img");
    newImage.style.maxHeight = "300px";
    newImage.style.maxWidth = "300px";
    newImage.id = "previewImage";
    newImage.src = e.target.result;

    var imageLabel = document.createElement("p");
    imageLabel.innerHTML = "Preview image:";
    imageLabel.id = "previewImageLabel";

    imageSelector.parentNode.insertBefore(
      imageLabel,
      imageSelector.nextSibling
    );
    imageSelector.parentNode.insertBefore(
      newImage,
      imageSelector.nextSibling.nextSibling
    );
  };
  if (image) reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  else {
    const prevImage = document.querySelector("#previewImage");
    if (prevImage) prevImage.parentNode.removeChild(prevImage);
    const prevImageLabel = document.querySelector("#previewImageLabel");
    if (prevImage) prevImageLabel.parentNode.removeChild(prevImageLabel);
  }
}
```

The file selector input has #image id. Note, this code deletes the preview image if there is no file selected.

I am just wondering why this happens. Can you think of a solution? Thanks.

Note: I am using chrome on ubuntu linux

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `FileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(fileElement.files[0])` and this code is inside `FileReaderInstance.onload = function(){}`, but you're not showing us enough code to determine your issue.

Comment: Ok I am adding full code, sorry

Comment: Why not just show us *(meaning everyone except me because it's getting late)* a working example with HTML and CSS.

Comment: This is added https://jsbin.com/wigawededo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Some of your content must go out of the screen. Try using overflow: hidden or try to decrease width of input/other elements.

Comment: Thanks for response, I tried adding overflow:hidden to the form. Now it occurs less frequently but still occurs when I try multiple times.

Comment: `@srknl`, that comment makes no sense.